# How to run a method when a window is terminated in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, methods, window

How would I run a method or a few commands after a window is terminated in my program? I know that you can use this to stop the application:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {
return YES;
}
```

but how do I run a specific set of code to i.e. run the `save` method when I close the main window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `-windowWillClose:` in your window delegate

https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillClose: